# lodash _.keyBy() converts number to string

Tags: typescript, lodash

is there a way for this conversion to be avoided? I see there's this interface

```
interface NumericDictionary<T> {
    [index: number]: T;
}
```

but can't figure out how to use it

Comment: Keys are string, what do you mean to do? Why can't you convert them after you extracted them?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have interfaces, where do you see that?

Comment: i want to use the above interface so they don't get converted to strings when doing `keyBy` and so that they are keyed by number instead. I can convert them after extracting them but it removes the elegance of the solution

Comment: @Barmar this is typescript, edited tags

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have numeric keys of objects, keys are always converted to strings.

Comment: gotcha that answers the question

Comment: edit: I figured out a clean way to make this work with typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by typing the result i.e.

res: Record<number, value> = _.keyBy(x, 'path')